# How can I reset font size for my entire website using bootstrap or CSS?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, font-size

I have a weird issue. I am working on an Angular 8 MVC C# application. The website works fine using default browser fonts. However, we have to include a department Nuget package for headers, footers and some menus. By including this, all my fonts on the website considerably reduce in size (7.5px or so). I tried changing font-size and font-weight in bootstarp 4.0 body tag to !important:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: 1rem !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

This did not help. What should I change in order to fix all html to default size ( I cannot change the Nuget package)?

Comment: have you tried setting the font to the `*` level?

Comment: `:root { font-size: 16px }` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
*,
html,
body {
  font-size : 1rem;
  font-weight : 400;
 }
```